# Error Publishing to Azure in VS 2010 - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, azure

I'm getting an Object reference not set to an instance of an object error when trying to publish a ASP.net web application to Windows Azure in Visual Studio 2010.  I am able to run this application in IIS, and the Azure emulator, without error.

I've gone through and checked all my references, checked the Azure configuration settings, and the web.config and can't figure out what's going on.  I have another application which isn't that different from this one, which has not problem publishing to Azure.

This is coming from Windows Azure Activity Log in Visual Studio.  It seems as though it's coming right around the time when it is about to verify the storage account.  Maybe it's related to that?

```
11:08:46 AM - Warning: There are package validation warnings.

11:08:46 AM - Preparing deployment for Repnet - 11/9/2012 11:06:35 AM with Subscription ID '********-****-****-****-************' using Service Management URL 'https://management.core.windows.net/'...

11:08:46 AM - Connecting...

11:08:48 AM - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

11:08:48 AM - Deployment failed with a fatal error
```

Comment: Try deploying it as a package manually.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I tried it this way, and it gave me more information, apparently I forgot to upload my SSL certificate!  So that was it, once I did that everything is all good.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `<connectionStrings>`
 element in the web.config file. If it has a ''`<clear/>` element remove it, afterwords publishing should work.

See [Link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/749901/error-when-i-click-publish-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object)